# Ruby: Create a symbol searching method

Tags: ruby

So this is supposed to be a method that tells you if there is a `+` symbol before AND after every letter (a-z). Can't figure out why it always returns false. An example of when it should return true is if the input is `+d+`. It should return false however if the input was `+d+d`

```
def SimpleSymbols(str)
  idx = 0
  while idx < str.length
    if str[idx].ord > 96 && str[idx].ord < 123  
      return false if str[idx - 1] != "+" || str[idx + 1] != "+"
    end

    idx += 1 
  end
  return true
end

SimpleSymbols(STDIN.gets)
```

Comment: This is working fine for me. What version of ruby are you using?

Comment: works for me as well

Comment: haha wow. I'm using coderbyte.com, doing the challenges. Should I send the link?

Comment: I misunderstood the question. I thought you were also checking to ensure that the string contained only lowercase letters and plus signs. I therefore deleted my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This returns true for me.  But I'm wondering if you're getting bit by a line termination issue?  Since gets() keeps the line termination, what do these two lines return in your environment:

```
SimpleSymbols("+d+d")
```

and

```
SimpleSymbols("+d+d\n")
```

?  That might provide a pointer to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you start the loop and idx is set to 0, the "str[idx - 1]" will equal -1. Setting the statement to check the last character not the first.

return false if str[idx - 1] != "+" || str[idx + 1] != "+"

So "f++d+" will pass as TRUE while it's actually false.

GL